# Functionality of flink processes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm studing Flink and I'm executing a little programs. I see that there is many process related to Flink. When I start cluster, it start the process of job Manager and the process of task Manager and they execute their program. When I start the application, it start a new process. In the process of task Manager there are a slots for execute the task, but what the new process do?

Answer (score 0):

In general, with how many processes you end up depends on how you execute Flink. Since you mentioned cluster, I'm assuming you running Flink in cluster mode. Then your new process is just the client process as described on the [concept/runtime](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/concepts/runtime.html#job-managers-task-managers-clients) page.

This client submits the user code and configuration to the jobmanager and periodically polls the job result to wait for job completion/failure (if configured to wait). The process is mostly idling though.